# Assign value to a field after checking a condition

Tags: postgresql, database-design, constraint, default-value

I have this query:

```
ALTER TABLE MERCHANTS
   ADD COLUMN merchant_image bytea,
   ADD COLUMN merchant_logo bytea,
   ADD COLUMN merchant_address VARCHAR(100),
   ADD COLUMN merchant_phone VARCHAR(50),
   ADD COLUMN order_type VARCHAR(15)
      CHECK(order_type IN ('TAKE_AWAY', 'HOME_DELIVERY','NO_ORDERING')),
   ADD COLUMN open_until TIME,
   ADD COLUMN order_until TIME
```

For `order_until` I have this condition: if `order_type` is `'NO_ORDERING'` then its default value should be `0`. How can I write this, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want to do? Adding a default value of 0 to the order_type table will cause anything that doesn't specify that field to fail the `CHECK` constraint you've outlined. Could you please edit your question and give more details on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Kassandry: I think the default is supposed to apply to `order_until`, but there's still plenty to be clarified here.

Answer (score 0):

`order_until` is data type `time`, which is an odd design - typically you would have [`timestamp` or `timestamptz`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) here to include the date. Be that as it may, the column cannot be <strike>`0`</strike>, which is not valid for `time`.

To get on with it, let's assume you want **`NULL`** instead, which would make sense for `order_type = 'NO_ORDERING'`. That's *simple* because the default `DEFAULT` value of any column *is* NULL and you needn't do anything extra. Seems like you want more than just a default ...

Next problem in your question: do you just want to enforce the rule or actually write `NULL` to the column (overwriting offending values), and if so, do that for `INSERT` and / or `UPDATE`?

**To enforce your rule (exactly):**

```
ALTER TABLE merchants ADD CONSTRAINT home_delivery_cannot_have_time
   CHECK (order_type <> 'HOME_DELIVERY' OR order_until IS NULL);
```

[The documentation:](http://Read)

> A check constraint can also refer to several columns.

Follow the link, there's more.

**[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/11a53/1)**